# Do I need a transit visa in Dublin with change of terminals (Indian citizen with US visa)?

Tags: air-travel, transit-visas, airport-terminals, dublin

I am an Indian citizen with a valid US visa traveling from Charlotte, USA to India via Dublin, Ireland and Abu Dhabi.

Charlotte to Dublin - American Airlines (landing in Terminal 1).
Dublin to Abu Dhabi - Etihad (departing from Terminal 2)

And I see from the Irish immigration website that Indian nationals do not require a transit visa, but I read somewhere that the transit visa is required in case of terminal change, irrespective of the country of citizenship.

It would be greatly helpful if someone could confirm whether I will need a transit visa or not.

**May 15 2018 UPDATE:**
I called Abtran who are the document processing center for Ireland visas and who also hold a paid customer service (charging at $2.90 per min) and here is the answer that I got. As an Indian citizen, a transit visa is waived for me if I am not moving between terminals. But the Dublin airport is designed in a peculiar way, and anyone who is moving between T1 and T2 will need to go landside (per Abtran there is no airside transit) and so people need to take the short-stay (like tourist) visa, as a transit visa will not be sufficient for this scenario. We re-booked the flight through another country, as we don't want to go through any more pain in the ***.

Comment: Welcome to Travel! If the Irish immigration website says Indian nationals don't need a transit visa, why would you credit a different opinion from another, non-official and unidentified source?

Comment: @Vishnu I’m not familiar with Dublin airport but this guide seems to indicate that it’s not possible to transit airside between terminals. http://www.dublinairportt2.com/transferring-between-t1-and-t2/ In which case you’d have to pass through immigration and would need a transit visa. http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa

Comment: @Traveler, thanks for the additional information. Vishnu, I'm sorry for the snark in my first comment. Irish immigration (the site cited by Traveler) says you don't need a visa if you're transferring to an onward flight at the same Irish airport, but the Dublin Airport info does suggest (without saying so) that you must pass through Immigration and Customs to get from T1 to T2. However, other online info like https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1649798-dublin-connection-t2-t1.html states there is, indeed, an airside walkway between T1 and T2.

Comment: from the link @David provided, the Aer Lingus website states clearly that the 2 terminals are connected airside to airside. https://www.aerlingus.com/travel-information/airport-information/dublin-airport-terminal-2/#/tab-0-map,con

Comment: Very good, @Traveller. Make it an answer!

Comment: Thank you @Traveler and @ David. One of the persons traveling with me contacted the Irish Embassy via twitter and they replied back stating we might need transit visa if we are switching terminals. So we are inclining towards applying for a transit visa to err on the side of caution.

Comment: Here's what they said - If you are remaining airside, you do not need a visa. However, as you are changing terminal you will need to apply for a short-stay visit visa. You can find out how to apply here: http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visit%20Tourist

Comment: Vishnu you may want to add your edit as a separate answer

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a visa to transit airside http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa Information online about connections between the two terminals at Dublin airport is a little confusing, however the Aer Lingus website clearly states that Terminals 1 and 2 are connected both airside and landside https://www.aerlingus.com/travel-information/airport-information/dublin-airport-terminal-2/#/tab-0-map,con

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation: coming in from Abu Dhabi in Terminal 1 and departing to the US from Terminal 2. Both Etihad and the Irish Consulate in San Francisco said that I will need a visitor visa. So I applied and got one (that took about two weeks at Irish Consulate in San Francisco).

However, when I actually reached Ireland, **the immigration officer in Terminal 1 said that it was not necessary**. That being said, I am not sure whether the airline will allow you to board without the Irish visitor visa.

Regarding going from Terminal 1 to Terminal 2: when you get out of the plane/gate, you will have to go towards Immigration. There are separate lines for EU and non-EU passport holders. Then beyond baggage claim, there is a shortcut to Terminal 2. The officer there led me directly to the security check at Terminal 2, allowing me to completely bypass the long line at Terminal 2 security. 
Also, FWIW, there is US CBP Preclearance at Terminal 2 which saves you time after landing in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Self-connecting passengers will be unable to use the flight connection facility.

If you have single PNR ticket:

From: pcmap-dublin.netlify.app/?fca=1

> Please note that the T1 Flight Connections airside access is only open
> 06:00 to 13:00. After that time all Flight Connections passengers must
> exit T1 arrivals and clear T1 Security or T2 Security via the
> departures level to gain access to their boarding gate. The T2 Flight
> Connection airside access is open 04:00 to 16:30.

https://www.dublinairport.com/flight-information/connections/connection-guide