# Do Indian citizens need Ireland Transit Visa at Dublin Airport on a journey from USA to India?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, ireland, dublin

I am travelling to India via Dublin and need to change flight, airline and terminal at Dublin Airport. It is one ticket though. Flights are American Airlines and Etihad. Do I need short stay visa or transit visa? I know Indians don’t need transit visas but I am more concerned about other factors like airlime boarding or terminal change.

I would like to know personal experience as this question has been asked but did not proceed with same travel itinerary.

Comment: I wanted to continue discussion on similar question but due to insufficient reputation couldn’t and advised to Ask a new question instead. Please share personal travel experience at dunlin airport.

Comment: @Giorgio not a dupe....apart from title nothing matches OP's problem

Comment: Can you provide your flight details?

Comment: As per the [newly linked question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114823/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-in-dublin-with-change-of-terminals-indian-citizen-with), as you will be changing terminals you need an Irish short stay visa (NOT a transit visa) because Terminal 1 and 2 are only connected landside (after entering Ireland)

Comment: @RedBaron In that case, what is the purpose of the Flight Connections option compared with the ‘self-connection’ route? https://www.dublinairport.com/flight-connections/self-connecting-passenger-information but the OP has one ticket.

Comment: @Traveller I have no idea, maybe its for flights departing from same terminal or maybe the airport information webpage is not very up-to-date. The other question is very recent (May 2018) and explicitly states that OP has been told that Terminal 1 and 2 are not connected airside.

Comment: I have contacted Dublin Airport and they said it is possible to use Airside transit to change terminals. I have asked more information about that. Will update once receive info.

Comment: @RedBaron flights are AA 722 and EY 48. In return its EY 45 and AA723

Comment: I have also started process for short stay visa. I wish I knew about this before. Would not have selected Layover at Dublin.

Comment: @J62 Best to check out visa and other entry requirements eg inoculations before booking a flight in future :-)

Comment: @Traveller - Agree. I checked for this as well but on www.cibtvisas.com as suggested by my booking agent. And that site says no visa required. But when I checked www.inis.ie they have mentioned extra scenarios when visa is required.

Comment: Here is the answer by Etihad ‘I need to collect my bags and check-in again at Dublin Airport even though it us single ticket but marketed by AA and not codeshare’

Answer (score 0):

AA lands at T1 while Etihad departs from T2 https://www.dublinairport.com/flight-information If your bags are checked through to your final destination the Flight Connections channel will get you to your departure gate in around 20 minutes https://www.dublinairport.com/docs/default-source/default-document-library/dublin-airport-flight-connection-guide.pdf?sfvrsn=2

Comment: Yes I am looking for personal experiences if anyone has. Everything is looking good on website still there are cases where airlines have denied boarding or passengers stuck at immigration mainly due to bags re checkin. So want to know that if airlines have denied check thru bags in any case even on single journey ticket for any reason per say different airline.

Comment: Eithad flies out of T1 and AA flies out of T2 (Not the other way around). Dublin Terminals 1 and 2 don't have airside connection as per [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114823/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-in-dublin-with-change-of-terminals-indian-citizen-with) so it looks like OP will need a short stay visa.